# How to pass the jellyfish?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm getting killed by the jellyfish that you can find when jumping into the sea and can't beat them. What is the trick?

I used potions etc... They just deal too much damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice, for now, would be not to bother. They don't always appear. You can get far enough into the sea levels to get some of the items without facing them if you're lucky. Just keep trying until you don't get them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried sneaking under them, **hiding down behind the 'sandbanks'** until they pile up, and then kill the few that come down to attack you. It's easier not to get swarmed. If you find one of them coming behind you, just go upwards. I also recommend getting *pink gloves* and using *acid rain*. Same with the seahorses which usually comes after, just poke up with a *fireball* or *acid rain*.

Comment: Additional note, with boots of introspection you can get below the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Crown with jaspers, monkey staff enchanted, lots of health and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too but when I tried it once and I was waiting. In a hole Jellyfish could not there anymore so I stayed there but sit and they formed a kind of row because they could not attack me. So i did every acid rain that lasted a long time because there were a lot of jellyfish. But perhaps that also work

Answer (score 0):

Use the sponge to shrink yourself and you can sneak underneath them when they pile up.